# JSON formatting for Java

Tags: java, json, format

Hi I need to produce a JSON file with a certain format. I'm stuck and advice on how to proceed with this. My code is below:

```
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Student {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a = -7;
    int b = 7;
    int k = 103;
    int order = 109;
    int px = 60;
    int py = 76;

    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    obj.put("name", "JEAN-LUC PALMYRE");
    obj.put("srn", "120299364");
    obj.put("ecc","");



    try (FileWriter file = new FileWriter("Jean-LucPalmyre_120299364_CO3326_cw1.json")) 
    {

        file.write(obj.toJSONString());
        file.flush();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.print(obj);

}
```

The output should be like this:

```
{
    "name": "MARK ZUCKERBERG",
    "srn": "000000001",
    "ecc": {
        "a": -2,
        "b": 13,
        "k": 103,
        "order": 109
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the code you posted is incomplete. The output with this code won't be the one you expected, but `{ "name": "JEAN-LUC PALMYRE", "srn": "120299364", "ecc": ""}`

Comment: yes but for the ecc part i'm not sure how to get the values into the required format. This is what i wanted to know. How to do this part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
 JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
 obj.put("name", "JEAN-LUC PALMYRE");
 obj.put("srn", "120299364");

 JSONObject objEcc = new JSONObject();
 objEcc.put("a",a);
 objEcc.put("b",b);
 objEcc.put("k",k);
 objEcc.put("order",order);

 obj.put("ecc",objEcc);
```